# Simulate the response of nonlinear systems exited by an impulse signal

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-system, python, simulation

I'm trying to replicate an algorithm, which requires to collect responses of the nonlinear system excited by impulse signals. Is there any chance to simulate the impulse response of nonlinear systems in python or matlab by using available tools? Or should I simulate by applying Volterra series to the nonlinear system?

Any hint would be appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: start with ```ode45``` matlab function

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It works!